# htaccess deny access specific url but with 1 exception

Tags: .htaccess

I want to deny access to urls starting with `/mapname` , so that urls like `/mapname/mapname2` and `/mapname/file1` etc, are blocked. But there is 1 url that I want to allow, for example  `/mapname/mapname.php/something/something/something.php/something` . How do I do this using htaccess?

To deny access I used the following code example. This worked, but I can't figure out how to allow specific urls.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /mapname
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single `RewriteRule` one can do this using negative lookahead:

```
RewriteRule ^mapname(?!/something\.php/allow/this/uri/?$) - [F,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
RewriteRule ^mapname/something\.php/allow/this/uri/?$ - [L]
#Deny any other uri string starting with "/mapname
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mapname
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I choose the other answer as right, because it is more compact :)